# How do i run individual unit test cases in Code composer studio?

Tags: unit-testing

Please suggest me on how to run individual test cases in CCS V6. I have unit test cases written for the C files function wise and module wise. I am new to CCS hence please advice on executing my test cases for individual C files and not taking all my project files. Thanks! Sai